# How to combine video and audio in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, instagram

**Elaborating Question:**

Instagram has this feature in which you can record your video through camera or select video from storage and add different song/audio to that video. You can post the same on to your post.

On viewing the post you see that the audio and video is combined playing and also
when you download the reel you get the whole video combined with audio.

How can this be achieved in React-Native ?

Any Plugins(Free or Paid) or Packages that can be used to achieve this would help.

Comment: this cannot be done in react-native. it can be done NodeJS, python or another technology. but i think python is best for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Video Editor SDK by IMG.LY](https://img.ly/video-sdk)

NPM Package : [react-native-videoeditorsdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-videoeditorsdk)

Comment: it requires a license key

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in react-native. it can be done NodeJS, python or another technology. but I think python is best for this.
Here is some example for you.

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311295/node-js-merge-audio-and-video-streams-and-pipe-it-to-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

Check this library

https://github.com/hiett/react-native-video-merger

```
import RNVideoEditor from 'react-native-video-editor';

    RNVideoEditor.merge(
    ['videourl.mp4', 'video2url.mp4'],
        (results) => {
            alert('Error: ' + results);
        },
        (results, file) => {
            alert('Success : ' + results + " file: " + file);
        }
);
```